# How do I see the values of the enchantments in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to see what the enchantment values are in Minecraft so I can use commands to give myself impossible enchantments such as a Riptide and Loyalty III trident for testing. For example, ***what's the value of sharpness?*** And what's the value of Smite? I would also like to see if Sharpness, Smite, and **Bane of Arthropods** stack. Can I get a full list of the values in the comments, something that's copy and pastable. Like `this.`

Comment: what do you mean by "value"

Comment: Are you asking for the legacy numerical IDs of enchantments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In snapshot 17w47a for Minecraft 1.13, use of IDs rather then Namespace was phased out.  You would now use the name of the enchantment, along with NBT data in a give command for the item you want.  I suggest using a [command generator](https://mcstacker.net) to generate these give commands in a simple fashion.